# Print accurate real time interim words from Google Stt

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, live-streaming

How to print real time text of spoken words from google stt. We can see in google voice search if we command like - stack overflow, instantly it prints words. I have my code bellow -

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string credentialsPath = "D:/Docs/GoogleSttFile.json";
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credentialsPath);
    string languageCode = "en-US";

    var speechClient = SpeechClient.Create();

    // Initialize audio input stream
    var audioStream = new WaveInEvent();
    audioStream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1); // Adjust format as needed

    var streamingCall = speechClient.StreamingRecognize();

    // Start streaming with the configuration
    var streamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig
    {
        Config = new RecognitionConfig
        {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
            LanguageCode = languageCode,
            EnableAutomaticPunctuation = true, // Enable punctuation
        },
        InterimResults = true, // Enable interim results
    };
    streamingCall.WriteAsync(new StreamingRecognizeRequest
    {
        StreamingConfig = streamingConfig,
    });

    var interimResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string lastInterimResult = string.Empty;

    // Handle audio data
    audioStream.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            streamingCall.WriteAsync(new StreamingRecognizeRequest
            {
                AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded),
            });
        }
    };

    audioStream.StartRecording();

    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

    // Start a new thread to listen for responses from the server
    var responseThread = new Thread(async () =>
    {
        await foreach (var response in streamingCall.GetResponseStream())
        {
            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                string transcript = result.Alternatives[0].Transcript;
                if (result.IsFinal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(transcript);
                    interimResultBuilder.Clear();
                }
                else if (IsSignificantChange(transcript, lastInterimResult))
                {
                    interimResultBuilder.Append(transcript);
                    // Split interim results into complete sentences based on punctuation
                    var interimSentences = interimResultBuilder.ToString().Split(". ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (var sentence in interimSentences)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Interim result: " + sentence + ".");
                    }
                    interimResultBuilder.Clear();
                }

                lastInterimResult = transcript;
            }
        }
    });
    responseThread.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop recording...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Stop the audio recording and finish the streaming call
    audioStream.StopRecording();
    streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
    responseThread.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool IsSignificantChange(string currentInterimResult, string lastInterimResult)
{
    // Customize this function to determine what constitutes a significant change
    // Here, we check if the current result is different from the last result.
    return !string.Equals(currentInterimResult, lastInterimResult, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

As an output of the speech - hello good morning, it is showing the results below :

```
Interim result: how.
Interim result: hell.
Interim result: Hello..
Interim result: hello would.
Interim result: Hello.
Interim result: Good morning..
Interim result: Hello..
Interim result:  Good morning..
Interim result: Hello.
Interim result: Good morning..
Hello. Good morning.
```

But my expected output of printing texts is just like as google voice search. When I say 'hello', instantly it will print hello, if I say 'good' it will print good instantly without passing any unusual words. final result is showing correctly without any issue. Thanks.

Google STT, NAudio has been used here.